# How to get path, row index and content of row in bash shell?

Tags: shell, text-processing, grep

I have a file and I want search some text in this file and export path of file, row index of content iIsearched and content of row.

I use this command:

```
grep -rnw 'path-file' -e 'patter'
```

but the result is:

```
tree.sh:1:abc xyz
```

How can I get each line in form:

```
tree.sh - 1 - abc xyz
```

Comment: What is `path-file`, a directory or a file?

Comment: this is a directory of file

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your `grep` supports `--color`:

```
grep --color=always -rnw -e 'pattern' 'path-file' | sed -e 's/:/ - /;s// - /'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it with awk:

```
$ echo "tree.sh:1:abc xyz" | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":| "} {print $1}'
tree.sh
$ echo "tree.sh:1:abc xyz" | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":| "} {print $2}'
1
$ echo "tree.sh:1:abc xyz" | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":| "} {print $3}'
abc
$ echo "tree.sh:1:abc xyz" | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":| "} {print $4}'
xyz
```

Since the original question has been modified I'm adding sed option:

```
$ echo "tree.sh:1:abc xyz" | sed -e "s/:/ - /g"
tree.sh - 1 - abc xyz
```

Comment: You `sed` will replace `:` if it contains in line content

Comment: @cuonglm This will work for OP's data. If he adds other type of data then I will update it.

Comment: I bet that's not the real data. `:` is very likely to occurs in line content.

Comment: @DawidGrabowski tks u, it works for me.

Comment: @VươngVũ Happy to help, and welcome. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted for others.